Use ffmpeg to play UDP stream and also analyze with ffprobe simultaneously
I have a UDP stream that I have running using ffmpeg that I want to see video on the client/player side
ffplay udp://127.0.0.1:51234?localaddr=127.0.0.1

along with the metrics using ffprobe. If I play with ffplay and try to run with ffprobe
ffprobe -show_streams -show_format "udp://127.0.0.1:51234?localaddr=127.0.0.1"

I get the error:
[udp @ 0000019319aef480] bind failed: Error number -10048 occurred
udp://127.0.0.1:51234?localaddr=127.0.0.1: Unknown error

Is this possible with the -tee command in ffmpeg? If not, is there a script that I could use to achieve this?
